# WSO2: Error validating open JPA Json file

Tags: json, spring, api, wso2, swagger

i have a problem in WSO2 ApiManagment: when i try to import my API from a URL i have an error.
I have installed the WSO2 version 4.0.0 and i have on my Spring project the Swagger version 3.0.0 with this dependency

```html
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I try this passage: I generated my Json file from this URL: http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
I read correctly the Json file, so i go on WSO2 page at this URL:
localhost:9443/publisher
then I copy-paste the Json URL on WSO2 at "OpenAPI Url" and I received an error: "Click away to validate the URL"
I click "away" but nothing happens.

So I tried to save my JSON as a file, then I went again on WSO2 and I clicked on "OpenAPI File/Archive", I uploaded my Json file and I received this error: "OpenAPI content validation failed!"
I tested the validation of my JSON file and its results were validated.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Paste your OpenAPI JSON file into https://editor.swagger.io and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! The JSON was clear but when i do the conversion from JSON to YAML into editor.swagger.io I have an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.